# Relationship between Interest rate and commodity prices

Tags: interest-rate

In section 4 of this [article](https://www.assurehedge.com/7-unwinding-carry-trades-that-crashed-the-markets/)

> 4. The Russian Rouble's spectacular crash Oil. Gas. Wheat. Iron. Cobalt.
>
> Russia’s status as a commodity superpower, and the high yields this
> can generate, has made the Rouble popular in carry trades (at least
> until its senseless invasion of Ukraine in 2022).
>
> But in 1998, investors couldn’t get out of the country fast enough.
> **And even massive 150% interest rates couldn’t persuade them to stay.**
>
> The trouble started in November 1997, when speculators decided that
> the Rouble was weak and bet on its value going down. At the time, the
> Rouble was pegged to the US Dollar, so the Russian government had to
> intervene, spending $6 billion of its foreign currency reserves to
> maintain the peg.
>
> **Then, commodity prices plunged, which reduced the country’s revenue
> significantly.** To compound its financial woes, the government wasn’t
> especially great at collecting taxes, and had just spent billions on a
> war in Chechnya.
>
> By June 1998, Russia’s debts were 40% higher than its tax revenue.
> Fearing the government would default, investors scrambled to get their
> money out of the country, with the result that the stock market
> crashed and the Rouble had to be devalued.
>
> In the aftermath, inflation hit 84%, leading to strikes and civil
> unrest. But the devaluation saved the Rouble by making Russia’s
> exports more competitive at the same time as trade in commodities
> boomed once more.

Did the plunged commodity prices have anything to do with interest rate?

Why did they plunged?

Comment: Russia produces (mines, grows..) these commodities, and exports them to other countries. There was a global financial crisis, mostly in Asia, starting in 1997 https://www.cnbc.com/2017/10/25/on-20th-anniversary-of-asian-flu-markets-still-feeling-the-effects.html . As the result of it, there was less demand for the commodies that Russia exports, and it earned less money exporting them than its budget planned.

Comment: + I don't agree with the option that you quote, that the financial crisis was caused by the US Federal reserve raising interest rates in 1997. Rather, the trigger was the emerging markets bubble bursting. Many investors had bought assets (equities, real estate, etc) in emerging markets such as Thailand, Philippines, Russia, etc hoping that these countries would become as rich as Japan soon. By 1997, it became clear that they were too optimistic, and the EM assets sold off, causing much turmoil everywhere.